# .* afters t-sql statement in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have problem with following statement. Could you tell me what is `EMD_1.*` ?

```
WITH EMD as (
    SELECT     
       ,attribute1
       ,attribute2
       ,attribute3
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY attribute1
                           ORDER BY attribute3) as _RN
       ,attribute4
       ,attribute5
    FROM         
       table_name1
)
select
    EMD_1.*
    ,isnull(EMD_1.attribute1,'_profitcenter nd') as ProfitCenterName
    ,EMD_1.attribiute2 as PC_ID
FROM 
    EMD as EMD_1
JOIN 
    table_name2
```

Comment: Means all columns from table `EMD_1`

Comment: Or are you asking what the result set will look like due to the partitioning?

Answer (score 2):

It selects all the columns from the EMD_1 alias (alias to the EMD table).

Answer (score 1):

`EMD_1` is an alias for `EMD`. `EMD_1.*` selects all the columns from `EMD_1`.

Take a look at the [**SELECT clause**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) syntax, the select list in the select clause can be either of the following:

```
...
<select_list> ::= 
    { 
      * 
      | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.* 
      | {
...
```

So you can put `*` or `tablename.*` or `table_alias.*`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify something - `EMD_1.*` does indeed mean "All columns from EMD_1" and EMD_1 in this case is just an alias (apparently for no good reason) for EMD.

However, this is **NOT** the same as saying `SELECT *` in the above query. If you use SELECT * then you will get **all** columns both from EMD_1 **AND** table_name2.

This is presumably why the author of the SQL has included EMD_1. before the *, because they only wanted all columns from EMD_1...

Answer (score 0):

EMD_1.* is just all columns from the EMD_1 table.

Answer (score 0):

EMD_1 is an alias for EMD, in this particular context you do not need to alias that table. Having different Alias's for the same table become important when you join a table to itself.

```
Select t1.*
From table as t1
inner join table t2
   on t1.column = t2.column
```